# Devise works different in two machines with exactly the same code and configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm using Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 5.2.2.

I'm very confused about Devise behavior. First, I had my project working in my localhost. The error began when I tried to put the project in a VPS.

The same code with the same gem versions and same operational systems works differently in two different machines, the VPS and my localhost.

The VPS:

```
    devise (4.7.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-i18n (1.8.2)
      devise (>= 4.6)
```

Entering in /users/sign_in:

[image]

After log in:

[image]

And the localhost:

```
    devise (4.7.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-i18n (1.8.2)
      devise (>= 4.6)
```

Entering in /users/sign_in:

[image]

After log in:

[image]

The code:

```rb
class Admin::HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_title

  def index
  end

  private

    def set_title
      @title = 'Home'
    end
end
```

```rb
class Admin::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Admin::User::SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'login'

  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :clients, controllers: {
    sessions: 'clients/sessions',
    confirmations: 'clients/confirmations',
    omniauth: 'clients/omniauth',
    registrations: 'clients/registrations',
    passwords: 'clients/passwords',
    unlocks: 'clients/unlocks'
  }

  #
  # Área do cliente
  #
  devise_scope :client do
    get 'area-do-cliente/entrar', to: 'clients/sessions#new'
    get 'area-do-cliente/meus-dados', to: 'clients/registrations#edit'
  end

  get 'area-do-cliente/pedidos', to: 'clients/orders#index', as: 'client_orders'

  devise_for :users,
             class_name: "Admin::User",
             controllers: {
    sessions: 'admin/user/sessions',
    confirmations: 'admin/user/confirmations',
    omniauth: 'admin/user/omniauth',
    registrations: 'admin/user/registrations',
    passwords: 'admin/user/passwords',
    unlocks: 'admin/user/unlocks'
  }

  namespace :admin do
    root 'home#index'

# Some other routes ...
```

I solved the VPS authenticity problem. Now it doesn't throw the error, but when I log in it redirects to the *wrong path* (not the admin root), and with `current_user` `nil`.

There are a lot of questions with the Devise authenticity problem and they say to put this in the controller:

```
protect_from_forgery
```

and I did, but now after log in `current_user` is `nil`.

The one thing different between the two environments, is that in the VPS I had Nginx with this config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name vps12441.publiccloud.com.br;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Why are devise getting different behaviors with exactly the same code (and application configuration) in two different machines?

How can I make it work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Use emphasis sparingly

You can put things in boldface or italics, but do this only when it is really necessary. Emphasis is used to draw extra attention to something. If almost everything demands extra attention, then nothing will get extra attention.

As a rule of thumb, before putting something in boldface or italics, ask yourself: if I could put only one thing in this post in boldface or italics, would it be this? If the answer is no, then don't.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/128421

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're on Rails 6? Rails 6 attempts to verify an authenticity token by default in production mode. I would guess that on the VPS your application is running in production mode, and trying to protect you from CSRF attacks, which it does not do in development mode, which is how it is running on localhost. You can confirm if I'm right a few ways, but if I am then adding `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to your `ApplicationController` should make the problem go away on your VPS solution.

Another option for development on your VPS would be firing up your Rails server in development mode: `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s`

Comment: I did what you say of add skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token to my ApplicationController. It works, but now i conclude: it's not a Devise but a Rails problem. I got the same issue out devise controllers. And not it all, now in some controllers i'm getting this error:

**Before process_action callback :verify_authenticity_token has not been defined**

My RAILS_ENV  is development in all machines